# engine runs rough for ~1 min, then starts ticking for a couple minutes, then fine

Tags: engine, rough-idle, kia

Vehicle: 2003 Kia Sorento, 193k miles
It started ticking 3 weeks ago while the wife was driving.  I test drove it, and the ticking quieted down to no tick over the day to and from work.  I drove it the next day after adding sea foam and no ticking until around 100 miles, when the engine started running rough, and it wouldn't keep a steady idle.  I pulled over and checked everything I could on the road, then it started up again, but the ticking was back.  Took it home and tore it down and put in new lash adjusters.  But after testing it out for about 30 miles, the engine was running rough (although barely noticeable this time) for about 30 secs, then the ticking for about 3 minutes.  Then the same thing happened around 20 miles later, but strong enough to lower the idle RPM again.  It also cleared up quickly, and the ticking stopped after about 3-5 miles.  I have only noticed the rough running when I am around 2k rpm, but just might be coincidence.  I have driven all day today (~70 miles) with no problems, no tick at all. Check engine light comes on when it starts running rough, then it will go off after ~30 miles.  I am waiting for a buddy to give me his code reader, will update when I do. 
Any thoughts or recommendations?

Side note...who ever designed the left valve cover with the hidden bolt, where you have to remove half the stuff attached to the engine should be shot. :)
Thanks for your time!
Ken

Comment: Did you get the codes read? If so, what are they?